# Configure jest run configuration inside WebStorm for Vue + TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webstorm

I want to execute all my tests within WebStorm, but I cant get it working. I generated a project with Babel, TypeScript and Vue using vue-cli 3.0.0-rc3. My run configuration is as follows:

[image]

However I get the following error:

```
● Test suite failed to run

/Users/calberca/Tmp/test-3/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:2
import "core-js/modules/es6.promise";
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string

  1 | import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
> 2 | import HelloWorld from "../HelloWorld.vue";
    | ^
  3 | 
  4 | describe("HelloWorld.vue", () => {
  5 |   it("renders props.msg when passed", () => {

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/__tests__/HelloWorld.spec.ts:2:1)
```

When I run `yarn test:unit` from console the test passes. But when I run `jest --config=jest.config.js` the test fail.

My initial thought is that it has to do with ts-jest not transforming the code with Babel, and vue-cli somehow toggles an option to do that and I want to use the same command, but I have no idea about what I should do to make it work.

*Note: I did this with a bigger project and like 80% of tests pass, but there are still tests that don't pass with similar errors regarding ES6 and beyond features.*

## Edit

It somehow got solved with a new update from Webstorm (2018.3) and I had to do nothing :)

Answer (score 1):

works for me using the following configuration:

[image]

I had to change the `jest.config.js` as follows to make this work:

```
module.exports = {
moduleFileExtensions: [
    'ts',
    'tsx',
    'js',
    'jsx',
    'json',
    'vue'
],
transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
},
moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
},
testMatch: ['<rootDir>/(tests/unit/**/*.spec.(ts|tsx|js)|**/__tests__/*.(ts|tsx|js))'],
snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-serializer-vue'
]
```

}

Comment: I generated a new proyect and that particular tests works, but on my project they won't. And the problems are very similar. It has problems with import and new JavaScript features

Comment: likely the issue is that your tests are not correctly transpiled; however I can't advise on fixing the configuration unless you provide a project

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to `jest.config.js` worked for me

```
 globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            skipBabel: true
        }
    }
```